# Should I do "Totems of Hircine" the 1st or 2nd time as a werewolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I am currently a werewolf, planning to cure myself for the time being, and some day get the Dawnguard plugin and then do some more werewolfing.

Does it matter whether I do the Totems quest now or after regaining lycanthropy? Will both get me the extra howls?

Comment: The best advice I could give you is to get them as soon as possible, you never know when things could go wrong in terms of bugs, and/or glitches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know it would not matter when you complete the quest so long as you are a werewolf when you do it. Both times, first or second, you will still receive your extra howls and werewolf perks.

Comment: In the meantime, I have finished the totems quest and then cured lycanthropy. I will try to remember to report back once I got Dawnguard (in some future Steam sale).